# Coming string replace for site meta description

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a multi-site built with different locations. We had to make a custom area to place title and meta information. Right now the title only outputs the shortcode for a company name that is set in the theme options. We have to other shortcodes that are present for the city and state. I updated the code for the title area but it only works for the last line of code for the state. I need all three codes to work.

```
**if($get_location['option_value'] == get_bloginfo('name'))
                {
                    # grab title tag from page ID
                    $get_title = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT meta_value FROM wp_'.$number.'_postmeta WHERE meta_key = \'title\' AND post_id = \''.$post->ID.'\''));

                    # grab company name
                    $get_company_result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT option_value FROM '.$td[0].' WHERE option_name = \'option_tree\''));

                    $get_city_result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT option_value FROM '.$td[0].' WHERE option_name = \'option_tree\''));

                    $get_state_result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT option_value FROM '.$td[0].' WHERE option_name = \'option_tree\''));

                    # clearn up returned value
                    $company = unserialize($get_company_result['option_value']);

                    $city = unserialize($get_city_result['option_value']);

                    $state = unserialize($get_state_result['option_value']);

                    # replace shortcode with company name
                    $return_title = str_replace('[company_name]',$company['company_name'], $get_title['meta_value']);
                    # replace shortcode with company name
                    $return_title = str_replace('[city]',$city['city'], $get_title['meta_value']);
                    # replace shortcode with company name
                    $return_title = str_replace('[state]',$state['state'], $get_title['meta_value']);

                    # if values are not empty/null
                    if($get_title['meta_value'] != '' or $get_title['meta_value'] != NULL)
                    {
                        $title = $return_title;
                    }**
```

Comment: You are updating the same variable `$return_title` 3 times. Use a different variable or some condition to evaluate which is the correct data you want to output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating the same variable `$return_title` 3 times. Use this code instead:

```
$return_title = $get_title['meta_value']; //put into a variable
# replace shortcode with company name
$return_title = str_replace('[company_name]',$company['company_name'], $return_title); //override variable with str_replace
# replace shortcode with company name
$return_title = str_replace('[city]',$city['city'], $return_title); //override variable with str_replace
# replace shortcode with company name
$return_title = str_replace('[state]',$state['state'], $return_title); //override variable with str_replace
```